# create arbitrary amount of duplicates in the dataframe until it reaches a certain capacity

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe `src_df` with certain amount of rows `num_rows`.

I want to create a new dataframe (`random_selection_df`) that would contain a subset of rows from the original dataframe, but it should duplicate rows (arbitrary like some row is duplicated 1 time, some row is duplicated 2 times and so on) to have the same amount of rows as the original `src_df`.

Basically I want to imitate the "foreign key" relationship between dataframes.

I tried to do like this

```
random_selection_df = src_df.select(col(column)).sample(0.5, self.seed)
fk_df = random_selection_df.withColumn(column, explode(array(random_selection_df[column], random_selection_df[column])))
```

But it essentially adds a single duplicate to each row. How to add random amount of duplicates until the `fk_df` has `num_rows` length?

For example to get from `src_df`

```
+-------+
|ID     |
+-------+
|     74|
|      2|
|     27|
|     84|
+-------+
```

to `random_selection_df`

```
+-------+
|ID     |
+-------+
|     74|
|      2|
+-------+
```

and then `fk_df`

```
+-------+
|ID     |
+-------+
|     74|
|      2|
|      2|
|      2|
+-------+
```